# android, new Intent from custom class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I wish to `startActivity(intent)` from a custom class.

when i try:

```
Intent listAllNumbers = new Intent(this, numbers.class);
listAllNumbers.putExtra("Data", jsonResult);
appContext.startActivity(listAllNumbers);
```

`appContext` being `getApplicationContext()` context passed as a parameter to the custom class (`AsyncTask`)

Usually i have ..`new Intent(MainActivity.this, numbers.class);` but i'm not instantiating the intent from MainActivity. I've tried putting the class name, but i get `Cannot resolve constructor`. What do?

Comment: Show you numbers.class code. Remember to folow up java code style and create classes with FirstLetter UpperCase

Comment: When you are starting, from another activity?

Comment: from inside a custom class. one that extends AsyncTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationContext is not allowed to start an Activity, you can read more about [here](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/).

You need to use the current context from your current Activity, like this:

```
Intent listAllNumbers = new Intent(this, numbers.class);
```

In fragments, this way:

```
Intent listAllNumbers = new Intent(getActivity(), numbers.class);
```

From another classes that not extends Activity or Fragment, you need to set the context by contructor or setter:

```
public void setContext(Context context) { // called by the activity or fragment
    this.context = context;
}

Intent listAllNumbers = new Intent(this.context, numbers.class);
```

Comment: how would i start the intent? this.context.startActivity(listAllNumbers) does't work

Comment: Do you have the error that not working? The number.class is declared in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: solved it with: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

thanks for your help :)